# BeagleBone Black Driving NFETs w/GPIO

Tags: mosfet, gpio, fet, beaglebone-black

*In short, I want to drive some NFETs directly from some of the BBB's GPIO.*

3 of the NFETs will pass 1-3 Amps of D-S current and 1 NFET will pass <1 Amp from the D-S.  As you may know the BBB's GPIO's Vin_H/L and Vout_H/L are like 2V/0.8V and 2.85V/0.45V respectively.

In addition, the source/sink currents on the BBB's GPIO's are like 4mA.  At 1st, I was going to directly drive the gates of two different NFETs (AO3422 and IRLR024N) but started looking for more margin in terms of (logic level) Vgs(th) matching but then starting thinking that the gate's Ciss is very important here (the larger the NFET the larger the Ciss) and now I am 2nd guessing if this is the right approach.  Throw in PWMing and possibly operating in the "ohmic" region (of the NFETs) may prove to be non-desirable for several reasons, ie, not fully turning on and creating excessive heat.

I am thinking of just driving these NFETs (BBB==>74ACT245==>NFET) with just a 74ACT245 (buffer) and be done with it for a simple solution and move on.  Will this scheme work?

Comment: Try the AO3400 which has a lower VGS(th) of 1.45V. This would seem quite adequate for your V(out) level of 2.85V, providing a 30V V(ds) is enough.  A 220 Ohm series resistor should tame the gate charge current.

Comment: Note that the Vout_H/L of 2.85V/0.45V is at the rated current. If you are driving a MOSFET gate, the GPIOs will drive close to the rails since the current is very low (after the gate is charged of course).